# Pattern for async testing with scalatest and mocking objects with mockito

Tags: asynchronous, scalatest, mockito-scala

I am writing unit tests for some async sections of my code (returning `Future`s) that also involves the need to mock a Scala object.
Following [these docs](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#mocking-scala-object), I can successfully mock the object's functions. My question stems from the fact that `withObjectMocked[FooObject.type]` returns `Unit`, where async tests in scalatest require either an `Assertion` or `Future[Assertion]` to be returned. To get around this, I'm creating `var`s in my tests that I reassign within the function sent to `withObjectMocked[FooObject.type]`, which ends up looking something like this:

```scala
class SomeTest extends AsyncWordSpec with Matchers with AsyncMockitoSugar with ResetMocksAfterEachAsyncTest {
      "wish i didn't need a temp var" in {
        var ret: Future[Assertion] = Future.failed(new Exception("this should be something")) // <-- note the need to create the temp var

        withObjectMocked[SomeObject.type] {
          when(SomeObject.someFunction(any)) thenReturn Left(Error("not found"))

          val mockDependency = mock[SomeDependency]
          val testClass = ClassBeingTested(mockDependency)

          ret = testClass.giveMeAFuture("test_id") map { r =>
              r should equal(Error("not found"))
          } // <-- set the real Future[Assertion] value here
        }

        ret // <-- finally, explicitly return the Future
      }
}
```

My question then is, is there a better/cleaner/more idiomatic way to write async tests that mock objects without the need to jump through this bit of a hoop? For some reason, I figured using `AsyncMockitoSugar` instead of `MockitoSugar` would have solved that for me, but `withObjectMocked` still returns `Unit`. Is this maybe a bug and/or a candidate for a feature request (the async version of `withObjectMocked` returning the value of the function block rather than `Unit`)? Or am I missing how to accomplish this sort of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refrain from using `mockObject` in a multi-thread environment as it  doesn't play well with it.
This is because the `object` code is stored as a singleton instance, so it's effectively global.

When you use `mockObject` you're efectibly forcefully overriding this `var` (the code takes care of restoring the original, hence the syntax of usign it as a "resource" if you want).

Because this `var` is global/shared, if you have multi-threaded tests you'll endup with random behaviour, this is the main reason why no async API is provided.

In any case, this is a last resort tool, every time you find yourself using it you should stop and ask yourself if there isn't anything wrong with your code first, there are quite a few patterns to help you out here (like injecting the dependency), so you should rarely have to do this.

Comment: makes sense, thank you